# How to remove routing in angular2 after making the folder as a dependency to another project?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular2-routing, node-modules

I have a testing angular project (lets call it *project1*) where I'm writing my components. I have to use routing in this project in order to navigate from component to component (organizational and esthetic's purpose).

I have another angular project (lets call it *project2*) which HAS in its node_ modules the component project-project1 (made available by referencing it through package.json) in project2.

**Problem**

When I have to fetch the components from *project1* to *project2* (simple angular forRoot routing in project2), a problem appears with forRoot conflict which is now in my *project1* and *project2*.

The problem disappears once I remove the routing from project1 in the node_modules from project2 but thats time consuming.

Is there a way to solve this problem, other than mannualy deleting the routes in my dependency (project1) or commenting code just to make project2 work?

Comment: In The copy of your project 1 in the node_module, can you replace forRoot  by forChild in it ?

Comment: And where are you calling your project_1, in your route with lazy-loading? Can you give us some code of how you use it in project 2

Comment: I cannot call forChild in anyway because I run this project in 2 ways, separately and together. I just need forRoot, no childs. Project1 is in node modules of project2 after npm install

Comment: The forRoot() must be 1 per app. In your case you are having 2. One from project1 and one from project2.
What build process are you using?

Comment: @tottomotto I perfectly aware of that. This is why I want to remove the other forRoot in my project1 but without losing too much time on it and deleting it line by line... Im using node and npm start which calls npm build

Comment: And what is triggered by the *npm build*? Is it a ng-cli project or angular-seed or something else?

Comment: ng cli project. yes..Npm build builds the project2 which has project1 under the node_modules

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Add a conditional statement for the forRoot() method inside the *project1*.
So everytime you're building it as a *standalone* app it will do **forRoot()** and when built as a *npm dependency*- **forChild()**.

```
// this is how you're getting the environment
import { environment } from './environment';
```

**Solution 2**

Add lazy-loading inside *project1* so the **cli** won't bundle all of the modules as one, but as separate. After that import OR lazy-load *project1* modules(not the *root*, it still has the *forRoot()*) inside *project2*, referencing it from the *node_modules*.

[Beware of this issue if doing lazy-loading from node_modules.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2601)

*If you need more help, please add some code.*

Comment: I´ll have a look at it, tnx.